# Set content type client side for css

Tags: css, client-side, content-type

My css is generated with php.

And I would like to set the content type to css but client side.

I know that server side, we can do `header('Content-Type: text/css');`

But is there a way to force the content type to css in the client side?

Comment: Since you're already generating it on the server side it only makes sense to set the content type on the server side, no?

Comment: @BoltClock It's a little bit difficult to explain. All the content of my website is in a database, with a php page generating it. And each thing I will write will apply for all other pages. (Including setting the header)

Comment: be carefull with generating css with php. Their is a reason why it is hardly ever done. It takes up server time and can cause problems with caching on the client side. Consider working with a preprocessor like LESS http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Since ` All the content of my website is in a database`, would it be possible to include the content type of each `content` alongside and use that to set the header?

Comment: @Vikdor Good idea! Maybe I will use this if there is no solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server has to be the one that sets the Content Type in the response headers. If you have some kind of weird limitation where you can't serve CSS files separately, consider loading the CSS into < style > tags on a global shared php page, anywhere in the header or footer html.

Comment: This one would be to the other extreme where a remote chance to associate any HTTP headers with the content for cache-control etc., are completely removed. The current way to serve it from DB is still bad but at least still an HTTP request :)